How to model transliteration (and translation) in a database?
I am working on a project in Django (backed by Postgres) to store manga titles, that will have values that should be translated and transliterated. Since I am starting from scratch, I figured my database should be well modeled (and normalized) to handle all kinds of strings that may be translated in English, Japanese and Romaji (as well as other languages). I found this article with a universal translation subschema that I like quite a bit, but I'm struggling to figure out how to store Romaji (as well as other transliterations) in that schema. I wanted to simply use locale codes to uniquely differentiate languages in the LanguageTable, but Romaji is not a language of its own, so it doesn't get a ISO 639 code. I was thinking a composite unique constraint of (language_code, character_set) might work, but then I also need some way of keying on character_set, and that seems like a big bag of worms, as I haven't found a standard that lists languages and their associated character sets.
Any advice for modeling this?

Don't overthink it. You are free to come up with your own language code for the Romaji of your choice. Standards like ISO are there to help, but they are not a law you have to follow if it is not useful for your case.

The subschema article fails to mention the actual simplest solution: Don't store multiple languages in the database at all. Instead choose one universal most common language for the context of your application and end users, and let the application convert it to a different language in real-time on load, when needed. This can easily be handled by a 3rd party API such as Google's Translate, and I'd recommend implementing that 3rd party API inside your own API so most of your consuming applications have one source of truth handling the translation.

@J.D. Not really a good solution as I'm storing manga titles which have already been officially (or fan) translated, and machine translation would likely only confuse people using the application.

@Vérace I don't really see how fuzzy match is relevant?

@LaurenzAlbe That's a good point, after sleeping on it, I realized I don't need to tie myself to ISO language codes.

I was thinking about something along the lines of a reverse soundex - but having Googled, it seems to be a fool's errand! I'll check in more detail before posting in future! :-) Comment deleted.

@RobRose Best of luck. It's not a usual goal you're trying to accomplish and will be difficult to do in a near-perfect way. In all honesty, if it's only the Titles that need to be stored in multiple languages, and there's only a small handful (3?) of those languages, since their translated counter parts aren't literal, and it's just a specific data point, it would probably be simplest to just have 2 additional columns with their translations stored in the same table and call it a day.
